# Экспорт из Excel в MySQL

Tags: excel, mysql

Доброе время суток!

Как правильно выполнить экспорт из Excel в MySQL?

Стоит dbForge Studio for MySQL. Все пробовал через него.

Пробовал импортировать как xls-файл - на странице выбора диапазона пусто, нажимаю "Дальше" - выскочило сообщение, что нет данных, либо они находятся за пределами листа.

Через кучу попыток удалось через dbForge Studio for MySQL импортировать XLS-файл, но японский все равно кракозябрами. При импорте для таблицы и для строк указывал UTF.

При этом, чтобы удалось выполнить импорт, пришлось убрать почти все строки. Закономерности не понял, но сначала мог вставить только если в excel`e было 5 строчек, затем если 9, а потом - до 50 дошел. Вроде все выполнял одинаково - открыл исходный файл, скопировал часть строк (5, 10, 50), вставил в другой (вставлял с самого начала, замещая содержимое), сохранял и отправлял на импорт. Каждый раз загружалось разное количество строк ("загружалось" - это если во время импорта не возникало ошибок)

В данном случае может быть и баг dbforge, но вопрос не в этом, т.к., насколько понял, мне все равно придется экспортировать в CSV, а с этим тоже проблемы.

Пробовал сделать экспорт из Excel в CSV, но MS Excel не признает при экспорте UTF, а он нужен - есть записи не только английском или русском, но и остальных языках.

Поставил Libre Office. Сделал экспорт в CSV в нем, указал UTF - экспортировалось. Попробовал загрузить - все языки нормально загрузились, а японский - кракозяброй.

Если экспорт данных из XLS в MySQL можно сделать не используя CSV, то как?

Если делать через CSV, то данный вопрос можно несколько переформулировать:

Как (или точнее чем) экспортировать XLS в CSV так, чтобы при импорте в базу нормально отображались различные языки? У меня, повторюсь, возникла проблема только с японским. Русский, немецкий, французский, хинди и еще некоторые экспортировались в CSV и записались в БД нормально.

На SO находил несколько похожих вопросов (про экспорт из XLS в CSV в UTF), но одного этого мне оказалось мало - у меня сразу после экспорта не отображался тот самый японский...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю что было...

Решилось все следующим образом:

- сделал экспорт в csv при помощи Libre Office (японский не отображается в отличии от других языков)
- залил этот файл на сервер, сделал импорт напрямую в базу
- при импорте указал кодировку UTF-8 (файл почему-то был в кодировке ANSI, хотя при экспорте было ясно сказано - экспортировать в UTF-8, причем - все языки, кроме японского, отображались нормально)
- перед получением данных с MySQL указал, что хочу все получать в UTF-8
- данные получены, все языки отображаются, даже японский